# How to find the number of additions involved to obtain a number N

Tags: algorithm

How to find the number of additions required to obtain an integer `N` such that, initially we have `x=1, y=1` you can perform `x=x+y` or `y=x+y` in each step. I have to know the minimum number of times i have to perform the addition to obtain `X=N` or `y=N`. (Eg. for 3 add X to Y , and then add Y to X . Value of X is 3 and value of Y is 2. so we have to perform at least 2 additions)

forgive me if the question was stupid

Please tell me which algorithm technique is better in solving this problem and how to approach this problem. thanks :)

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, please post what you tried till now and tell what's wrong with that implementation.

Comment: @skypjack i am sorry man i didnt ask u the code i only want u to set me upon a right path n help me by telling which algorith design technique is best for solving this kind of a problem .. :) thanks for answering :)